# How to update maven version on ubuntu machine?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, maven

I am working on Ubuntu linux machine. When I open a terminal window and type :

```
mvn -v
```

I got the output:

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-1)
Java version: 1.6.0_26
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.32-33-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

As you saw above, my current **maven** version is **2.2.1** , I am wondering, how can I update my maven to verstion 3 ?

What I tried: I have downloaded maven v3.0.3 binary version, and add the `/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin/` path in **.bash_profile** file, but when I use `mvn -v` command, it still shows version 2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the path on .bashrc instead, also remember to restart you terminal application after the changes

you need to add something like this, perhaps?

```
export PATH=$HOME/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: Explanation: .bash_profile is only included for login shells, but not for shells in terminal emulators like xterm. That is why you very rarely need to change .bashrc. Additionally, remember to put /apache-maven-3.0.3/bin at the FRONT of the path.

Comment: Thanks, why add it in .bash_profile does not work but add in .bashrc works?

Comment: as @thiton explained, the gnome-terminal that you are probably using loads .bashrc during the application start-up, if you login to linux console directly (like when you do ctrl+alt+F6) then .bash_profile is what gets loaded as part of the login process.